# How to auto-connect interactively to Embedded Derby Database

Tags: java, database, maven, jdbc, derby

I'm using Intellij IDEA to program a Maven Java Project that's using an embedded Derby database.

from my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.14.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
    <version>10.14.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: Intellij External Libraries]

I've discovered how to run ij interactively by making a new class that executes the main() method of `org.apache.derby.tools.ij`

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class runij {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:derby:codejava/webdb1;create=true";
        try {
            org.apache.derby.tools.ij.main(new String[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it auto-connect to the db url, `jdbc:derby:codejava/webdb1`, so I don't have to manually type `connect 'jdbc:derby:codejava/webdb1';` into it every time?

Answer (score 0):

No thanks to the random downvoter but I found out how to do it from [this page](http://zetcode.com/db/apachederbytutorial/ij/).

I changed the program a little bit - the original wasn't getting the arguments correctly.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class runij {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:derby:codejava/webdb1;create=true";
        try {
            org.apache.derby.tools.ij.main(args);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added an `ij.properties` file to the root of the project containing this:

```
ij.database=webdb1
ij.protocol=jdbc:derby:codejava/
```

Then added a run configuration to add `-p ij.properties` to the arguments when executed.

[image: Run configuration]